# Get indices of rows with consecutive values of 0 from large Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains energy consumption per half an hour. I'm trying to get lists of indices of rows that have no energy consumption for a long period of time. In other words, I'm trying to get a list of indices that contain consecutive values of 0 in a particular column. I use the following code and it seems to work fine for a while but then it starts adding lists of indices that are not 0.

```
import more_itertools as mit

indices = df.loc[df[df.columns[2]] == df[df.columns[2]].isnull()].index.values.tolist()
outages_indices = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices)]
long_outages_indices = []
for i in outages_indices:
    if len(i) >= 8:
        long_outages_indices.append(i)
```

For example, in row 849246 the value is indeed 0, but in row 1543677 the value is 0.105, but it is still part of the list.

First few rows of the DataFrame:

```
LCLid            tstp                           energy(kWh/hh)
MAC000002        2012-10-12 00:30:00.0000000    0.0
MAC000002        2012-10-12 01:00:00.0000000    0.0
MAC000002        2012-10-12 01:30:00.0000000    0.0
MAC000002        2012-10-12 02:00:00.0000000    0.0
MAC000002        2012-10-12 02:30:00.0000000    0.0
```

Desired output (which I already, but it's incorrect):

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...],
 [861958, 861959, 861960, 861961 ...],
 [862015, 862016, 862017, 862018, ...], ...]
```

EDIT: Solved it. When I was concatenating multiple CSV files into one Pandas DataFrame, the index numbering would start at 0 again when a new file was concatenated. I reset the index numbering and that solved my problem.

Comment: Please review [mcve] and share your DataFrames as well as a desired output

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you for your comment. I don't think it's wise to upload the entire 1.4GB dataset, so I've added the first few rows of the DataFrame and a desired output, which, in terms of format, I already have, but it also contains wrong indices.

Comment: Zarif... can you create small dataset that generates the error seen in your script, the let SO community provide an solution with this test dataset?

Comment: @ScottBoston The problem was in the index numbering when I concatenated multiple csv files into one Pandas DataFrame. I had to reset the index numberings. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `groupby` with `cumsum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'energy':[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]})

# mark the non-zero
s = df.energy.ne(0)

# groupby
new_df = df.groupby([s, s.cumsum()]).apply(lambda x: list(x.index))
```

gives you:

```
energy  energy
False   1         [1, 2, 3]
        3         [6, 7, 8]
True    1               [0]
        2               [4]
        3               [5]
dtype: object
```

and those indexes of interest are those with `False` level-0 index. that is

```
new_df.loc[False]
```

gives you:

```
energy
1    [1, 2, 3]
3    [6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

Comment: The problem was in the index numbering when I concatenated multiple csv files into one Pandas DataFrame. I had to reset the index numberings. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is close, but I think there's a mistake in the condition used to extract indices with zero energy.  You have:

```py
. . .
indices = df.loc[df[df.columns[2]] == df[df.columns[2]].isnull()].index.values.tolist()
. . .
```

This is a strange way to find the index of zero-energy rows.

The following works for me:

```py
import pandas as pd
import more_itertools as mit

df = pd.DataFrame({'energy': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})

# find the indices with zero energy
indices = df.loc[df['energy'] == 0].index.values.tolist()

# extract long outages
threshold = 4  # minimum length for an outage to be considered "long"
outages_indices = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices)]
long_outages_indices = [l for l in outages_indices if len(l) >= threshold]
```

If you also want to include `None` values for energy, then you could do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import more_itertools as mit

df = pd.DataFrame({'energy': [0, None, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, None, 0, None, 1]})
df = df.fillna(value=0)

# find the indices with zero energy
indices = df.loc[df['energy'] == 0].index.values.tolist()

# extract long outages
threshold = 4  # minimum length for an outage to be considered "long"
outages_indices = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices)]
long_outages_indices = [l for l in outages_indices if len(l) >= threshold]
```

Comment: The problem was in the index numbering when I concatenated multiple csv files into one Pandas DataFrame. I had to reset the index numberings. Thank you for your response.